# Open ios app if exists if not open in app store in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

```
  const uri = "myapp://";
    const appStoreUri = "https://www.apple.com/in/ios/app-store/";
      const clickedAt = +new Date;
      window.open(uri);
      setTimeout(() => {
          if (+new Date - clickedAt < 2000) {
              window.location.href = (appStoreUri);
          }
      }, 500);
```

This opens both app and app store, i am unable to restrict opening app store if app exists.